# hash_map is saving each key/val pair even when keys are equal

Tags: c++, hashmap, key-value

Hey guys, I am using a hash_map to relate strings to one another, with this code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <hash_map>

using namespace std;
using namespace stdext;

struct StrCompare : public stdext::hash_compare<string> {
 unsigned int operator()(const string str) const {
  unsigned int hash = 0;
  unsigned int len = str.length();

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i++)
   hash = 31 * hash + str[i];

  return hash;
 }

 bool operator()(const string str1, const string str2) const {
  return str1 == str2;
 }
};

int main() {
 hash_map<string, string, StrCompare> m;

 m["asdf"] = "fe";
 m["asdf"] = "asdf";

 for (hash_map<string, string, StrCompare>::iterator i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); ++i)
  cout << i->first << " " << i->second << endl;

 system("PAUSE");
}
```

The problem is that the output is:

```
asdf asdf
asdf fe
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Why is this happening? I have tried printing the hashes each time, but the hash is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From some of the details of your example, it looks like you're using MSVC. Microsoft's `hash_map` uses a comparison function that works in conjunction with the hash function to provide an ordering for keys that hash to the same value. This is different than SGI's specification of `hash_map`.  Specifically (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s1byw77.aspx):

> For any value `_Key1` of type `Key` that precedes `_Key2` in the sequence and has the same hash value (value returned by the hash function), `hash_comp(_Key2, _Key1)` is false. The function must impose a total ordering on values of type `Key`. The function supplied by hash_compare returns `comp(_Key2, _Key1)`, where `comp` is a stored object of type `Traits` that you can specify when you construct the object `hash_comp`. For the default `Traits` parameter type `less<Key>`, sort keys never decrease in value.

So while changing the comparison function to return `str1 != str2` seems to work for your test, it's not really correct.  It'll confuse the `hash_map` in the situation where two different strings happen to have the same hashcode.

Comment: So what should I do instead? I can't glean what to do from that info you pasted.

Comment: @James: I think you just need to `return (str1 < str2)`.  Some quick testing shows that `return str1 != str2` doesn't confuse the hash map as much as I thought it might. However, according to Microsoft's docs the `hash_comp()` function with 2 parameters must provide a "total ordering", which returning `str1 != str2` doesn't do. Or you can follow Jerry Coffin's suggestion and move to `unordered_map` which is supported in VS2008 and later (you might need a service pack or some other update in =VS2008 to get it) and which doesn't require the comparison function to provide an ordering.

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons `hash_map` didn't make it into C++0x is that there were a number of conflicting implementations, and little in the way of solid specification.

I'd switch to what was accepted into C++0x instead. `std::unordered_map` may have a long, clumsy name, but the semantics are well-defined; it will *not* store duplicate keys (for that you'd use `std::unordered_multimap` instead).

Answer (score 0):

Oh, apparently I'm using the

```
bool operator()(const string str1, const string str2) const
```

function wrong. Instead of

```
bool operator()(const string str1, const string str2) const {
    return str1 == str2;
}
```

it should be

```
bool operator()(const string str1, const string str2) const {
    return str1 != str2;
}
```